# Where should I put state initialization code in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Should Vuex store keep only the code of state structure and how to modify that state (mutations, actions), or also the actual state initialization and values?

I started wondering about it, when my state initialization code become more complex, because I don't see any natural place in Vuex architecture to put this code into.

Let's say I have such a store:

```
export default {
  state: {
    list: []
  },

  mutations: {
    addItem(state, { item }) {
      state.list.push(item);
    }
  }
}
```

If the list starts empty, it's enough. But what if I have default values for the list and also want to store the list in *LocalStorage*, so that I can preserve it's value between page loads.

```
const STORAGE_LIST_KEY = 'list';

const LIST_DEFAULT = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'item 1'
  },
  {
    id: 33,
    name: 'item 33'
  }
];

function initializeList() {
  let savedList = localStorage.getItem(STORAGE_LIST_KEY);
  return savedList ? savedList : LIST_DEFAULT;
];
```

Is there some natural place in the Vuex store architecture, where I should put `initializeList()` function? (e.g. In a Vue component I would put `initializeList()` into `methods` part of the component) Or maybe the store is just about the structure and the initialization code belongs to the Vue components?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your initialization state will be some sort of mutation or action depending upon the needs of async and side effects. This actions should be fired only once during initialization.

This mutation/action will then be triggered from root instance or sufficiently higher level component. You can also split the initialization of entire application state into smaller mutations or actions.

The advantage of this approach is you can split your Vuex store and dynamically load Vuex module (lazy loading).

In your case, since you wish to inflate/deflate state from local storage (which is a side effect), it makes sense to make an action.

Comment: Paitl: I used to think that actions are all about asynchronous operations. My initialization doesn't have any async code, so I rejected the idea of putting it into actions. Now I realized actions can be more than this.

Comment: But where do I dispatch that initialization action? I don't see a way to do that inside the state code.

Comment: @RobertKusznier, Either from root instance or sufficiently higher level component.

Comment: Get it. Thanks.